# Python no callstack when spawning concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python

I'm spawning multiple threads using the below code. When there's a problem the code doesn't die and a stacktrace printed, it just dies silently. If I remove the `executor` and run on same thread, I get a stack trace.

Is there a way to spawn the thread and still get the stack trace on error?

```
import concurrent.futures

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_cpus) as executor:
    for something in something_else:
        future = executor.submit(my_func, arg1)
```

Comment: It will throw an exception when you'd try to retrieve result. Store all futures somewhere and try to call [`Future.result()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result). Quote from *docs*: *"If the call raised, this method will raise the same exception."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For convenience of exception handling, `Future` will throw an exception on [`Future.result()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result) method, so you can call it inside `try .. except` block.

So you can just patch your code:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_cpus) as executor:
    futures = []
    for something in something_else:
        futures.append(executor.submit(my_func, arg1))
    
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        try:
            result = future.result()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception:", e)
        else:
            # do something
```